# How do I use a core data Integer 64 property?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, properties, nsnumber

I want to have an Entity property in Core Data be a 64-bit integer. Since the model is going to run on iOS, and as far as I know these devices are not 64-bit, I figured that `NSNumber` was the way to go (core data gives you the option of objects or scalar properties for primitive types).
I'm assuming that `NSNumber` will internally take care of keeping track of a suitable representation for 64 bits.

Now, I need to subtract 1 from this "64 bit" property in my entity at some point (in case you didn't guess, the 64 bit property is the max_id parameter in the Twitter API), but to do so, I first need to unbox the number inside the NSNumber property.

So should i get the intValue? longValue? unsignedIntValue? unsignedLongValue? long long? which one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you already know the type (64 bit integer), you don't need to check for it.

To get a 64 bit integer out of a NSNumber, do one of the following:

```
NSInteger myInteger = [myNSNumber integerValue];
int64_t   myInteger = [myNSNumber integerValue];
```

In order to just add one to it, you can use something like this:

```
myNSNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[myNSNumber integerValue]+1]];
```

Note that iOS **does** have 64 bit data types like `int64_t` and `NSInteger`.

**EDIT:**
If the only reason that you are using `NSNumber` is to store the 64 bit integer, you can just declare the property like this in your model subclass and skip the unboxing/boxing altogether:

```
@property (nonatomic) int64_t myIntValue;
```

Note that core data does this by default if you select the **Use scalar properties for primitive data types** option of the **Create NSManagedObject Subclass** feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in a `NSNumber` category:

```
-(int64_t) int64value
{
    if (sizeof(short) == 8)
        return [self shortValue];
    if (sizeof(int) == 8)
        return [self intValue];
    if (sizeof(long) == 8)
        return [self longValue];
    if (sizeof(long long) == 8)
        return [self longLongValue];

    return -1; // or throw an exception
}
```

Comment: sorry are you saying that there's no way of telling in which format I should be getting the value out of the NSNumber by default? Doesn't seem to make sense. If CoreData is telling me I can store a 64-bit integer in an NSNumber, shouldn't there be a simple way for me to subtract 1 from that NSNumber without caring about how it is represented internally?

Comment: myNSManagedObject.myNSNumber.objCType throws an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS... and the number is set. I can see it in the debugger and print it to the console. what gives?

Answer (score 0):

To get the C type contained in NSNumber use objCType

Example

```
NSNumber *myFloat = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.5f];
NSLog(@"%s", [myFloat objCType]);
```

Will print "f" as it contains a value of type float.

Also, check out @encode() which will return a C type character.

Example

```
NSNumber *myFloat = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.5f];
if (strcmp(myFloat) == @encode(float)) { 
    NSLog(@"This is a float");
}
```

Also

```
NSNumber *myFloat = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.5f];
CFNumberType numberType = CFNumberGetType((CFNumberRef)myFloat);
```